# Python String check

Tags: string, python-3.x, numbers

Can somebody tell me how to check to see if a user's input contains a number and only contains numbers and letters?

Here is what i have so far:

```
employNum = input("Please enter your employee ID: ")

if len(employNum) == 8:
    print("This is a valid employee ID.")
```

I would like to print the last statement after all the checks are done. I just can't seem to figure out how to check the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> employNum = input("Please enter your employee ID: ")
Please enter your employee ID: asdf890
>>> all(i.isalpha() or i.isdigit() for i in employNum)
True
>>> employNum = input("Please enter your employee ID: ")
Please enter your employee ID: asdfjie-09
>>> all(i.isalpha() or i.isdigit() for i in employNum)
False


>>> def threeNums(s):
...   return sum(1 for char in s if char.isdigit())==3
... 
>>> def atLeastThreeNums(s):
...   return sum(1 for char in s if char.isdigit())>=3
... 
>>> def threeChars(s):
...   return sum(1 for char in s if char.isalpha())==3
... 
>>> def atLeastThreeChars(s):
...   return sum(1 for char in s if char.isalpha())>=3
... 
>>> rules = [threeNums, threeChars]
>>> employNum = input("Please enter your employee ID: ")
Please enter your employee ID: asdf02
>>> all(rule(employNum) for rule in rules)
False
>>> employNum = input("Please enter your employee ID: ")
Please enter your employee ID: asdf012
>>> all(rule(employNum) for rule in rules)
False
>>> employNum = input("Please enter your employee ID: ")
Please enter your employee ID: asd123
>>> all(rule(employNum) for rule in rules)
True
```

Comment: wow, that was fast. Thank you! is there also a way to check if there is a certain number of letters or numbers? For example, if the employNum had to contain 3 numbers?

Comment: @WhooCares: Check out the edit. If you want more rigorous checks, you might look at regular expressions (comment if you want me to write it up)

Answer (score 0):

`.alnum()` tests if a string is all alphanumeric.  If you need at least one digit, then testing the digits individually with `.isdigit()` and looking for at least one can be found using `any()`:

```
employNum = input("Please enter your employee ID: ")

if len(employNum) == 8 and employNum.isalnum() and any(n.isdigit() for n in employNum):
    print("This is a valid employee ID.")
```

References: [any](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) [alnum](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) [isdigit](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)